# Manipulating images using external style sheet

Tags: css, image

What is the best way to manipulate an image using an external style sheet? 
Not getting a response with the code below:

```
<div id="poster"><img src="squatchposter.jpg" alt="Squatch Poster"></div>

#poster {
    background-image:url('squatchposter.jpg');
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Wouldn't the background-image on the div be covered by the image from the img element?

Comment: Are you sure the image exists?

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="squatchposter.jpg" cssclass="poster ">

#poster {

width: 400px;
height: 500px;
background-position: center;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the div rather than the image itself.  Give the image tag an id attribute, then reference that id in the stylesheet.